# Online Database

Tags: database, android

I want to write an application that reads blogpost from the internet and then present in my own way.

The blogposts are stored in databases, so I figured that the only thing I had to do was to query an online database for the posts that I want to show.. But I can´t find a way to opoen a connecion to an online database...

anyone out there with a solution to my problem?

//Narancha

Comment: Most blogs don't allow public access directly to the database used for storing the posts.

Comment: What is wrong with reading the RSS feed and storing the results of that locally?

Comment: Is this your blog, or third-party?  If it's your blog on your server, you should be able to accomplish this, however you'd need the credentials.

Comment: no it´s a wordpress blog

Comment: Please see my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408784/how-to-check-username-and-password-in-a-postgresql-server-from-android/10414602#10414602 It explains what I THINK you want to accomplish in short. You should be able to build upon that.

Answer (score 0):

if the blog you are interested in, has an RSS feed, you can connect to this and use xslt to transform this to html and use css to style that

Comment: Thx for the advice Robert, it will surely be helpfull but I really want to use the database not because I want to learn as well. There are some other applications that I am planning that will need online databases as well.