# How to check username and password in a PostgreSQL server from Android?

Tags: android, postgresql, android-intent

I am using the Android 2.2 API. I want to know how to connect to a PostgreSQL database server.

I am new to this and so have no ideas, so please help me with some sample code.

Comment: take a look at this tutorial [http://appliedcoffeetechnology.tumblr.com/post/10657124340](http://appliedcoffeetechnology.tumblr.com/post/10657124340)

Comment: I dont have ans even i had tried once..you seem to be ERP dev trying to make Android app for you..anyways..one of my frnd did that..will talk and let you know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually don't connect directly to a database.
To achieve the results you want, you can do a RESTful request.

This means, send either a JSON string or xml file to a server(which you can program in php, ruby and what not)

I'm not going to give you sample code cause there are literally tons of code on a simple google search "android restful login"
[Example tutorial](http://timewasted.net/?p=127)

The process is usually:

Enter login credentials on android device -> send post request to server -> validate credentials to the database(postgres in this case) -> send verification back -> android device act upon verification(usually by loading a new activity as a result if logged in successfully)